# Reading Java property groups from a file

Tags: java, properties, load

Is it possible to read different property groups from a Java file, without manual processing?

By "manual" I mean reading the file line by line, detecting where the start of a property group is and then extracting the corresponding key-value pairs. In practice, this means reinventing (most of) the wheel that the Properties.load() method constitutes.

Essentially, what I am looking for is an easy way of reading, from a single file, multiple groups of properties, with each group being identifiable, so that it can be loaded in its own Java Properties object.

Comment: Do you mean like an INI file?  A common way to do this is to use a prefix for your properties group1.prop1= ... group1.prop2= ... group2.prop1= ... see log4j properties.

Comment: That seems like something a proper markup language like XML would be best for.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I you want to use `java.util.Properties` you can use prefixes. In .properties file:

```
group1.key1=valgroup1key1
group2.key1=valgroup2key1
group2.key2=valgroup2key2
```

and read them like this:

```
class PrefixedProperty extends Properties {
    public String getProperty(String group, String key) {
        return getProperty(group + '.' + key);
    }
}
```

and using:

```
/* loading, initialization like for java.util.Properties */
String val = prefixedProperty.getProperty("group1", "key1");
```

You can also use [ini4j](http://ini4j.sourceforge.net/index.html) with windows ini files.

Another, better way is using own, custom structured file  (for example XML).